# Can't hide content after it being visible. Also, how to shorten the code

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have 4 links in my menu; about, archives, categories, and links. If I click on "about" the content for "about" is being visible. If I then click on "categories", the content for "about" will be replaced with the content for "categories".

So far so good, but I can't hide the content if I click on the link for the content that being currently visible. [Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/4zdLfcqg/).

```
$('body').on('click', '#page', function() {

    var page = $(this).attr('data');


    if($('.menu-pages').is(':visible')) {
        if(page == 'about') {
            $('#about').show();

            $('#archives').hide();
            $('#categories').hide();
            $('#links').hide();


        } else if(page == 'archives') {
            $('#archives').show();

            $('#about').hide();
            $('#categories').hide();
            $('#links').hide();


        } else if(page == 'categories') {
            $('#categories').show();

            $('#about').hide();
            $('#archives').hide();
            $('#links').hide();


        } else if(page == 'links') {
            $('#links').show();

            $('#about').hide();
            $('#archives').hide();
            $('#categories').hide();
        }



    } else {
        $('.menu-pages').show();

        if(page == 'about') {
            $('#about').show();

        } else if(page == 'archives') {
            $('#archives').show();

        } else if(page == 'categories') {
            $('#categories').show();

        } else if(page == 'links') {
            $('#links').show();
        }
    }

});
```

How can I make the content for the pages hide when I click on the link in my menu, after I have made the content for the page visible? And how can I make the code shorter?

Comment: `$()` can be passed a list of ids as in `$("#id1, #id2, #id3")`, which would reduce the size of your code for `hide()`. Also you already have a `page` variable which matches the id of the element to target so `$("#" + page)` will target the one to show. So hide all then just show the one you want, 2 lines to do all that part.

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context...

Comment: And to hide the stuff that has been displayed using the same button simply use `:visible` again and instead of just using `show` use `hide` instead. `$("#" + page)[$("#" + page).is(":visible") ? "hide" : "show"]()`

Comment: @gillesc That's true :) Many thanks for the code in your last comment. But it only stacks up all pages - not hiding the previous page

Comment: Last comment is not the code to do it all, you just didn't get it. Accepted answer is basically what I said to do but with extra variable created to cache query that are made only once....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it much more easily

```
    var selector = '#' + page;
    var isVisible = $(selector).is(':visible');
    var all = $('#about, #archives, #categories, #links');
    all.hide();
    if(!isVisible)
        $(selector).show();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvyf6ka8/1/)

Comment: That worked to shorten the code! Awesome! Now to the first question: hiding the pages. Replacing `all` with the content of the variable works too. 3 lines becomes 2 lines :P

Comment: Take a look at imtheman's solution. That user succeeded what I'm after. But I want a shorter code, of course

Comment: That's exactly what I want! :)

Comment: The `else` part is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do the first part by using `.is(':visible')`.

```
$('body').on('click', '.menu-link', function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('data');
    $('.menu-pages div').each(function() {
      if (this.id != page)
        $(this).hide();
    });
    if ($('#' + page).is(':visible'))
      $('#' + page).hide();
    else
      $('#' + page).show();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cvyf6ka8/3/)

Comment: That worked like a charm but isn't there any shorter solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not too difficult, but there is something important to change in your sample code. HTML doesn't allow "sharing" element IDs. You have multiple elements with the same id (`'page'`). That's non-conformant and should be avoided.

As for the JS part, this will work (After changing the IDs):

```
$('body').on('click', '[id^="page"]', function() {
    var page = $('#' + $(this).attr('data'));
    var isVisible = page.is(':visible');
    $('.menu-pages>div').hide();
    if(!isVisible)
    {
        page.show();
        $('.menu-pages').show();
    }
});
```

And a fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/4zdLfcqg/)